# get list of servers Ebean+Play

Tags: oracle, playframework, ebean

I need to get a list of all existing servers in the `application.conf` file, I take a look to `EBean` class, but i only found how to get an specific server `Ebean.getServer("test")`, also this returns an `EbeanServer` object, and i need a string value.
This is part of my application.conf:

```
db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//178.20.26.25:1521/orcl"
db.default.user="TEST1"
db.default.password="test1"

db.test.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
db.test.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//178.20.26.26:1521/orcl"
db.test.user="TEST"
db.test.password="test"

ebean.default="models.*"
ebean.test="models.*"
```

My expected output is a list that contains (`default`,`test`). Does anybody know a way to get this without parsing hole file?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code will give set instead of list:

```
Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) play.Play.application().configuration().getObject("db");
Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
```

If you want to do it in `type safe` way and get rid of compiler warning:

```
Set<String> keys = play.Play.application().configuration().getConfig("db").subKeys();
```

Both examples will return subkeys of `db` key which is `[default, test]`.